# Cannot get the value out of firebase with .getValue()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Java, Android, and Firebase. What I am trying to do here is read what's already uploaded to firebase, but the code doesn't work. I put a breakpoint and found that it doesn't even run the listener. What is the problem here? Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my database on Firebase:

[image: Database Structure]

This is the code I used to retrieve the information from the database.

```
//in Main Activity
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 

//Rest of the code is within onCreate()
mDatabase.child("9099").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 String number = dataSnapshot.child("Number").getValue().toString();
                 String time = dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue().toString();
                 String chan1 = dataSnapshot.child("Channel1").getValue().toString();
                 String chan2 = dataSnapshot.child("Channel2").getValue().toString();
                 testing.setText(String.format(time));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: `What I am trying to do here is read what's already uploaded to firebase, but the code doesn't work.` i'm going to assume that the `onDataChange` listener is for when data changes, not for reading value currently in firebase, but i could be wrong

Comment: @a_local_nobody That makes perfect sense but I cannot find an equivalent for `getValue()` which can only be called from `dataSnapshot` within `onDataChange`.

Comment: i'm by no means a firebase expert so i'm sure someone will be able to answer your question :)

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code make sure you unlock reading data in the rules of  the database in firebase console

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I got `Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used` when using Log.d.

Comment: @a_local_nobody `onDataChange` actually fires with the current value straight away. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events "This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes."

Comment: @jessicaTheCat Let's try a different `onCancelled` in that case. The simplest one I use is `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. If you put that in, does it throw any exception?